# Nested CASE..WHEN - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

1. If Tab1.Col1 = Tab2.Col1 then get the Stats1 field from the Table 2
2. If Tab3.Col3 = Tab2.Col3 then get the Stats3 field from the Table 3
3. If Tab2.Col2 = substr(Tab3.XYZ,1,2) then pass Stats1 (from above Step 1 as Com_Desc) else Stats3 (from step2 as Com_Desc)
4. If Com_Desc derived from step 3 is NULL or Blank, pass -1

I want to implement the above logics using case when statement. Have written the query but unable to populate the -1 value when both stats1 and stats3 is NULL
Below is my Query -

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN (Tab2.Col2 = substr(Tab3.XYZ,1,2)
THEN ((CASE WHEN Tab2.Stats1 is NOT NULL THEN Stats1 
      ELSE (CASE WHEN Tab3.Stats 3 is NOT NULL THEN Stats3
            ELSE -1
            END) 
      END)
 ELSE END)COM_DESC
FROM Tab1, Tab2, Tab3
WHERE Tab2.Stats1 IN (SELECT Tab2.Stats1 
                      FROM Tab1, Tab2 WHERE Tab1.Col1 = Tab2.Col1)
AND Tab3.Stats3 IN (SELECT Tab3.Stats3 
                    FROM Tab2, Tab3 WHERE Tab3.Col3 = Tab2.Col3);
```

Comment: Your main query does join the three tables (and you should _really_ get used to a proper explicit `JOIN` syntax rather). And please specify which DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Comment: Use IsNull(Tab.Stats, ''). also use explicit joins.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a sketch, some things in your description I don't understand. For example, in step 4, what is returned if it is not -1?

```
select coalesce(nullif(case when Col2 = substr(XYZ,1,2) 
                            then stats1 
                            else Stats3 
                       end, ''), '-1)
from (
    select Tab2.col2
      , Tab3.XYZ
      , case when Tab1.Col1 = Tab2.Col1
             then Tab2.Stats1
        end as stats1
      , case when Tab3.Col3 = Tab2.Col3 
             then Tab3.Stats3
        end as stats3
    from Tab1, Tab2, Tab3
    where ...
)
```

Comment: But those are strings, should it return '-1' if com_desc is null or space?

Comment: Yes, Lennart if both Stats1 & Stats3 is null then it should return -1

Answer (score 0):

I don't get how you join the tables, but your CASE can utilize COALESCE instead (returns the first not-NULL value, which is just a shortcut for a more complicated CASE):

```
CASE
   WHEN (Tab2.Col2 = substr(Tab3.XYZ,1,2)
   THEN COALESCE(Tab2.Stats1, Tab3.Stats3, -1)
END COM_DESC
```

Maybe you have to add an `ELSE -1`, too